# Como colocar o picker para começar com "Selecione" no React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Eu quero colocar o **picker** para começar com: "Selecione", a unica alternativa que eu encontrei foi determinar um **Picker.item** com **label="Selecione"** e **value=" "**. Porém fica com uma aparência desagradável na hora que o usuário vai selecionar, olha a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu código está assim:

```
  <Picker
      selectedValue={this.props.genero}
      onValueChange={this.props.modificaGenero}
      style={{ height: 35, width: 150 }}>
      <Picker.Item label="Selecione" value="" />
      <Picker.Item label="Masculino" value="masculino" />
      <Picker.Item label="Feminino" value="feminino" />
   </Picker>
```

Eu tenho certeza que isso é uma prática errada de programação.

Comment: Em meus projetos acabo usando da mesma maneira que você fez. Seguindo essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/42209072/9671639 do soen, acredito que seria uma maneira normal de resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas, tambem não sei uma forma de ocultar o primeiro item dos selects, mas tem uma coisa que você pode fazer! Você pode passar uma propiedade **color="#00000090"** no primeiro item, para dar uma opacidade no texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, conseguimos um contraste com os demais itens.

Comment: Ficou uma alternativa bem legal! Obrigado.